# Disable syntax expansion on cursor hover

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, plugin-vimwiki

I use Neovim with Vimwiki for a personal wiki of mine. I frequently use its syntax for changing typeface; for example _ _ for italic and * * for bold.
The syntax is expanded when the cursor is on a line containing it: *text* is expanded to _text_, **text** is expanded to **text** etc.

This is useful when editing, of course, but it might become a bit annoying when I'm simply reading.
My question is: is there a way to disable syntax expansion while maintaining syntax highlighting?

Thanks.

Edit: the solution is `set concealcursor=n` (thanks to Christian Brabandt)

Comment: :h concealcursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set concealcursor=n`, prepended with `tabdo` and `windo` to make it work everywhere.